# Span-like type in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

If I want to create a C++ function with Eigen that accepts a matrix as a parameter I can do the following:

```
void f(const Eigen::MatrixXf& mat) { /*...*/ }
```

but if the data is not in an `Eigen::MatrixXf` then I need to create one to hold it and duplicate the (potentially large) data under its ownership.

Does Eigen provide a "non-owning" matrix-like reference type/template in the spirit of `std::string_view` and `std::span` that will accept an `Eigen::MatrixXf` object as an argument, but will also accept a packed "multidimensional layout" raw (even arbitrarily strided) array of floats in some fashion?

If so, what is that type called and how is it used?

Perhaps `Eigen::Map` ?  But that doesn't seem to work the same way as the others?  Can you use it as a function parameter?  How?  Or is there another type for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, `Eigen::Map` is non-owning. You can pass it via the `Eigen::Ref` type or using a templated parameter (see http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

`Eigen::Ref` is what you are after.  From Eigen docs...

> ### Writing Functions Taking Eigen Types as Parameters
>
> Eigen's use of expression templates results in potentially every expression being of a different type. If you pass such an expression to a function taking a parameter of type Matrix, your expression will implicitly be evaluated into a temporary Matrix, which will then be passed to the function. This means that you lose the benefit of expression templates.... [etc]
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <Eigen/SVD>
> using namespace Eigen;
> using namespace std;
>
> float inv_cond(const Ref<const MatrixXf>& a)
> {
>   const VectorXf sing_vals = a.jacobiSvd().singularValues();
>   return sing_vals(sing_vals.size()-1) / sing_vals(0);
> }
> ```

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html